# jq to filter logs that match either of two conditions

Tags: json, select, command-line, jq

How to use jq to filter logs that match either of two conditions?

Say I have logs like this:

```
{ "level": "info", "value": 3 }
{ "level": "debug", "msg": "start" }
{ "level": "debug", "msg": "end" }
```

I'd like to filter logs that has either `level=="info"` or `msg=="end"`, so the query should select the first log and the last log line:

```
{ "level": "info", "value": 3 }
{ "level": "debug", "msg": "end" }
```

How can I use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for that?

I tried `jq 'select(.level="info") || select(.msg="end")'` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `or` keyword.

```
select(.level == "info" or .msg == "end")
```